# Asymptotic behaviour of solutions to elliptic PDE

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Let $u$ be a solution (in the distributional sense) of
$$
\Delta u = \delta_r
$$
on $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ open, $r \in \Omega$.
Let $w$ be a solution of
$$
Aw = \delta_r
$$
where
$A = \partial_{x^i}(a^{ij}\partial_{x^j})$, with $a^{ij} \in C^\infty(\Omega)$, $a^{ij}(r) = Id$ and $(\partial_{x^k}a^{ij})(r)=0$ for all $i, j, k \in \{1,2 \}$.
Does it follow that, in a neighborhood of $r$, $u-w$ is bounded?

One could go about it saying: let's find a uniform bound for the laplacian of $u-w$ outside of $r$ (by elliptic regularity, $u$ and $w$ are smooth outside of $r$), and then from this somehow deduce boundedness of $u-w$. But, for instance, $\log(|x-r|)$ is harmonic and unbounded, so this does not work. What am I missing?

Comment: I'd rather Taylor expand $a^{ij}$ in a neighborhood of $r$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of $u-w$, I think it's easier to show that $u-\log|x-r|$ and $w-\log |x-r|$ are both bounded. For former this is clear because it's harmonic. For the latter,
$$
\begin{split}
A(-w+\log |x-r|)&=-\delta_r + \sum_{ij} (\partial_{x^i} a^{ij}) \partial_{x^j}\log|x-r| + \sum_{ij}  a^{ij}\partial_{x^ix^j}\log|x-r| \\ 
 &=\sum_{ij} (\partial_{x^i} a^{ij}) \partial_{x^j}\log|x-r| + \sum_{ij}  (a^{ij}-\delta^{ij})\partial_{x^ix^j}\log|x-r|  \end{split}$$ 
Here $\delta^{ij}$ is Kronecker's, not Dirac's.

The $n$th  derivative of $\log $ is $O(|x-r|^{-n})$ but the terms $\partial_{x^i} a^{ij}$ and $(a^{ij}-\delta^{ij})$ decay fast enough to offset that. You get an equation of the form $A(-w+\log |x-r|)=f$ with reasonable $f$ (vanishing at $r$), from where the regularity of $-w+\log |x-r| $ follows.

Comment: wouldn't the same estimates work also for $A(-w+3\log|x-r|)$? In the first equality you use $\Delta \log |x-r| = 0$, the same would work also for $3\log|x-r|$.

Comment: @Second No, it would not. You would have $3a^{ij}-\delta^{ij}$ in the second line, which is not small.

Comment: Yes, thanks! The only thing that puzzles me are these pointwise calculations with something that does not have a pointwise sense...

Comment: @Second That's good; my computations are on the formal level, without justification. To perform them rigorously, you should manipulate the weak form of the equation along the same lines (i.e., multiplied by $\varphi$ and with one derivative thrown over at $\varphi$).